# Restrict a user to go to back pages from the browser back button after log out in struts 2 login web application?

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am making a Struts 2 web app in which after log out one can go to back pages from the browsers back button which i don't want in my app.I also using a custom interceptor before every request to authenticate users.but it also not working in desire way. My code is as follows

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>loginlogout</display-name>
<filter>
<filter-name>struts</filter-name>
<filter-   
class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-   
class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/action/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>  
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>bloack_jsp_access</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"></constant>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/action">
<interceptors>
<interceptor name="secure" class="com.inter.Authentication"></interceptor>
<interceptor-stack name="secureStack">
<interceptor-ref name="secure"/>
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
</interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>

<action name="loginAction" class="com.action.Login">
<result name="success" type="redirectAction">
 <param name="actionName">task</param> 
 <param name="namespace">/action</param>
</result>
<result name="input">/login.html</result>
</action>
<action name="logoutAction" class="com.action.Login" method="logout">
<result name="success">/login.html</result>
</action>
<action name="task">
<interceptor-ref name="secureStack"></interceptor-ref>
<result>/welcome.jsp</result>
<result name="login">/login.html</result>
</action>
</package>
```

**LoginAction.java**

```
package com.action;
import java.util.Map;
import model.User;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Login extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String userName;
private String userPass;    

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getUserPass() {
    return userPass;
}
public void setUserPass(String userPass) {
    this.userPass = userPass;
}

private SessionMap<String, Object> session;


public SessionMap<String, Object> getSession() {
    return session;
}

@Override
public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
    this.session=(SessionMap<String, Object>) session;      
}


private boolean validateUser(User user){
    if(userName.equals("sandip") && userPass.equals("12345")){
        return true;
    }else
    return false;
}

@Override
public String execute(){
    clearFieldErrors();
    User user=(User)session.get("user");
    if(user!=null){
        return SUCCESS;
    }else{
        User u=new User(userName,userPass);
        if(validateUser(u)){
            session.put("user", u);
            return SUCCESS;
        }else{
            addFieldError("invalid", "invalid login credentials");
        }
        return INPUT;
    }
}
 public String logout(){
    session.remove("user");
    session.invalidate();
    return SUCCESS;
}
}
```

**Authentication.java(interceptor)**

```
   @Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
Map<String, Object> session=actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();     
    User user=(User) session.get("user");
    if(user==null){
        return ActionSupport.LOGIN;
    }
    else{
        return actionInvocation.invoke();
    }
}
```

**login.html**

```
<form action="action/loginAction" method="post">
User Name:<input type="text" name="userName"/>
Password :<input type="password" name="userPass"/>
<input type="submit" value="login"/>
</form>
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
hello <s:property value="#session['user'].userName"/><br/>
<a href="action/logoutAction">logout</a>
```

Comment: I STRONGLY hope you don't use that **not-intented** style of XML / HTML formatting in real life :|

Comment: what is not-intented style of XML/HTML

Comment: lol... not INDENTED, my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i need to set the appropriate HTTP header attributes to prevent the dynamic content output by the JSP page from being cached by the browser.

that is like this

```
<%  
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); //HTTP 1.1  
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0  
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server  
%>
```

Comment: The same effect can be achieved by using meta tags in the HTML header:
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT">

Comment: And better yet by an interceptor.